# How strong is Chi Chi?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

How do Chi Chi's strength compare to the rest of the Z-Fighters. Since she managed to train Goten who is immsensely strong, is she stronger than Mr. Satan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Chi Chi does not have the ability to use Ki and also cannot fly. Hence, that would automatically make her weaker than the rest of the Z-Fighters. Even in terms of Physical Strength, Chi Chi's power is substantially weaker than even Yamcha.
- The only fighter she might be comparable to in  **terms of Physical strength** would be Chiaotzu. She did have a higher power level than him during the martial arts tournament. However, Chiaotzu with his psychic abilities would easily win. Also, Chi Chi was a lot younger at the time of the martial arts tournament and hence must've grown weaker with age.

  Training Goten doesn't imply Chi Chi is strong. Goku, who is at a Universe busting level of strength, would still train under Master Roshi. Even if Goten is born with massive physical strength, he would require someone to teach him basic Martial Arts which Chi Chi is definitely aware of.

  If you were to compare Chi Chi with Videl, one can easily conclude Videl is stronger in terms of physical strength and also, the fact that she is aware of using Ki and can also fly. With regard to Satan, it's pretty hard to determine who exactly of the two is stronger. Satan is often underestimated in terms of power when he as a matter of fact, did win all those Tournaments the Z fighters didn't take part in(And only cheated against Android 18). We also see him manage to pull 3 buses just by himself which I highly doubt Chi Chi would be capable to do. At the same time, Chi Chi has way better Martial Arts training in comparison to Mr. Satan.

Hence, if the two of them were to fight, I personally believe Chi Chi would most likely win under all circumstances. Mr. Satan is known for underestimating all his opponents heavily and spends half his fight showboating and would easily be caught off guard by Chi Chi. At the same time, Mr. Satan doesn't have the Raw Power to take out Chi Chi in one blow and hence Chi Chi's advantage in technique, might get the better of him.

Answer (score 1):

Her PL puts her at 130, which is a little lower than base Roshi at the start of DBZ.

She's still weaker than Yamcha and Krillin even at the end of the original DB as during the 23rd World Martial Arts Tournament when Goku fought Tien, both of them moved so fast that they disappeared with only Krillin and Yamcha being able to see them fight.

Also, Goku at a PL of over 260 after he had killed King Piccolo was trained by Mr. Popo and Kami with part of his training being to dodges lightning which Chi Chi can't do. Scaling to Vidal, her father, it's unlikely Chi Chi is bulletproof to handguns.

Answer (score 1):

According to Weekly Jump #31, by the time Chi-chi marries Goku, she has a power level of 130, that would be close to the power level of master Roshi by the time Goku and Tien Shinhan fought, or after Piccolo killed Raditz.

[List of power levels](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Power_Levels)

This link [Power levels Daizenshuu 7](https://www.taringa.net/+comics/dragon-ball-daizenshuu-7-niveles-de-poder_xbd66) claims the Daizenshuu 7 states Mr Satan power level is 139, by the time of the Buu Saga (other links claim the same). So Chi-chi and Mr Satan would be about the same, if you take both sources (Daizenshuu 7 and Weekly Jump) as canon. Both sources are probably official (written by someone in the companies which created Dragon Ball), but that doesnt necessarily mean the numbers came from Akira Toriyama's head (the creator of Dragon Ball)